# What's wrong with Wubi install?

Tags: installation, windows-7, wubi

I have a Windows 7 32 bit (Home Premium) on my **HP Laptop**. I decided to take the easy way to install Ubuntu and that is by using Wubi.

Having gone over a few tutorials on Wubi, I decided to let it do its task.
I let it install. I saw the Ubuntu option during boot and hence I selected it and pressed enter.

I saw the Ubuntu purple screen and then my screen went black. All the other lights in the laptop were on. The volume rocker, the wifi, power and so on. I let it sit for about 15 mins but since I did not get any response whatsoever, I had to forcefully shut it down.

Dismissing it as a fluke, I restarted the laptop and repeated the same procedure. I got the same result.

Well, what made it go wrong ?
For now,  I have uninstalled it with the hope of reinstalling it once I know what went wrong.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: @Jobin yes, sir. I do have a dedicated graphics card.

Comment: Which Ubuntu were you using with Wubi?

Comment: @ThomasW. The one it downloads by default.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Which Ubuntu OS are you trying to load with Wubi, 12.04, 12.10, or 13.04?

Comment: @ThomasW. Sir, I am not doing anything apart from double-clicking the `wubi.exe` that I downloaded from site :)

Comment: @LittleChild - what version of Ubuntu did you download - the site offers 12.04 & 13.04 - it also offers 32bit and 64bit.  Please add to your question what you downloaded.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom here you go http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer It is 12.04 LTS I believe :)

Answer (score 1):

WUBI is not supported with 13.04 and the newer versions. It's also not available with UEFI or windows 8. More here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows